# Using Cursor Adapter with multiple table cursor(inner join)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor, inner-join

I need two tables for my search. and i used inner join to get this two. But this two different table has some same column names(which i need). how can i differentiate this columns.

Here is what i did.

```
  final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Products p INNER JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryID=c._id";                           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
```

and i m using this cursor in my CursorAdapter to set my listview cell fields.

```
  prodName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
  prodCategory.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
```

As you see these are suppose to different values from different tables. But they show same value(name) because my inner join has this field 2 times and i dont know how can i separete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `*` name the columns you are querying and use an alias, for example:

```
SELECT p.name as pname, c.name as cname, ...
```

and then

```
prodName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pname")));
prodCategory.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cname")));
```